# Azure WebJobs - add trigger without attribute?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am building a continuous job that listens for Azure queue messages. Using the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to) I have something like this:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.UseEnvironment("development");
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}

public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")] string myQueueItem,
    ILogger log)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm not a fan of the magic `QueueTrigger` attribute found at runtime. Is it possible to add a trigger function manually? I'm imagining something like:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.UseEnvironment("development");
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddQueueListener("myqueue-items", Run); // no magic attributes, compiler error if Run function is deleted 
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}

public static void Run(
    string myQueueItem,
    ILogger log)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use manual triggers, you don’t need to use `QueueTrigger` attribute, but, as described in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#manual-triggers): **To trigger a function manually, use the `NoAutomaticTrigger` attribute.**

Therefore, I think whether you are using **Automatic triggers** or **Manual triggers**, you must add a trigger with attributes, which is necessary!